# wildcard allow-from uri in clientaccesspolicy.xml failing for Silverlight access to WCF

Tags: silverlight, wcf, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I've successfully created and am currently using a clientaccesspolicy.xml file to expose my WCF to my Silverlight client, with an allow-from domain uri of `http://*`.  I'd like to tighten it up by using a more specific uri like `http://www.foobar.com` or `http://*.foobar.com`, but when I use those uris, I get SecurityExceptions in my Silverlight client.

For reference, here is the currently working clientaccesspolicy.xml:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<access-policy>

  <cross-domain-access>

    <policy>

      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">

        <domain uri="http://*"/>

      </allow-from>

      <grant-to>

        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>

      </grant-to>

    </policy>

  </cross-domain-access>

</access-policy>`

I've tried changing http-request-headers to "*" to no avail.  And I've verified that wildcard uris (and resource paths) work for me when securing non-WCF resources like .txts or .pngs.  My clientaccesspolicy.xml is living in the same directory as the .svc.

I can't use a crossdomain.xml, as that doesn't allow specific uris (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250(VS.95).aspx).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "http://" from the URIs.  For example:

```
<domain uri="*.foobar.com"/>
```